# How to prove that if $AB = A + B$ then $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - 1}$ is an eigenvalue for $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm struggling with a problem in linear algebra where I have to prove that:

> Given $AB = A + B$ and $ 1 \notin \sigma (A) \cup \sigma(B)$ where $\sigma$ represent the spectrum of a Matrix and $\lambda \in \sigma(B)$ then the quotient :  $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - 1}$ is an eigenvalue for A (  $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - 1} \in \sigma(A)$ )

I have proved before this that A is invertible iff B is invertible, it has also asked me to prove that :

$$\prod\limits_{\lambda_i \in \sigma(A)}(\lambda_i - 1)  \prod\limits_{\lambda_i \in \sigma(B)}(\lambda_i - 1) = 1$$

But I couldn't find a way to do it, how can I prove both questions ?

Comment: What is $\lambda$ in the given situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$A(B-I) = B$. Suppose $Bv = \lambda v$, then $A (\lambda-1) v = \lambda v$, or
$Av = {\lambda \over \lambda -1} v$.

Comment: Thank's, that's a very clever observation, I tried to prove the reciprocal :   $$ AB - B = A $$ and $$Av = \lambda v$$ then we multiply both sides by v and replace : $$ AvB - Bv = \lambda v B - Bv = \lambda v$$ and by some  rearranging we get the same for the reciprocal

Comment: What about the last question for the product ?

Comment: Well, this gives a relationship between **all** the eigenvalues of $B$ and the eigenvalues of $A$. Perhaps you can use that fact to show the result?

Comment: The broad result (details omitted) is that given some function $f$ then if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $f(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(A)$. In the above, $f(x) = {x \over x-1}$

Comment: Yes, also how to prove that if B is diagonalisable then A is diagonalisable too ? I started with something like this  : $B$  is diagonalisable then $$B = PDP^{-1}$$ then I would multipley both side on left by A and then by $B^{-1}$ I get $$A = APDP^{-1}B^{-1}$$ but this leads to nothing, does it ?

Comment: If $B$ is diagonalisable it has a basis of eigenvectors. These are also eigenvectors for $A$. Hence $A$ is diagonalisable.

Comment: Why are they also the eigenvectors of A ? they have different eigenvalues as proven previously

Comment: (I am not claiming that the eigenvalues are the same.) If $Bv = \lambda v$ then $A v = {\lambda \over \lambda -1} v$. Since the eigenvectors form a basis, you can diagonalise $A$.

Comment: Oh I got it, Thank's for the clear explanantion !

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 2):

To see 
$$\prod\limits_{\lambda_i \in \sigma(A)}(\lambda_i - 1)  \prod\limits_{\lambda_i \in \sigma(B)}(\lambda_i - 1) = 1$$

fix an $i$ and look at $$\begin{split}
(\lambda_i-1)\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i-1}-1\right)
&=\frac{\lambda_i^2}{\lambda_i-1}-\left(\lambda_i+\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i-1}\right)+1\\
&=\frac{\lambda_i^2}{\lambda_i-1}-\left(\frac{\lambda_i(\lambda_i-1)}{\lambda_i-1}+\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i-1}\right)+1\\
&=\frac{\lambda_i^2}{\lambda_i-1}-\frac{\lambda_i^2-\lambda_i}{\lambda_i-1}-\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i-1}+1\\
&=\frac{\lambda_i^2}{\lambda_i-1}-\frac{\lambda_i^2}{\lambda_i-1}+\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i-1}-\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i-1}+1\\
&=1
\end{split}$$

There's a little more to show. You'll need to also show that every eigenvalue of $A$ has the form $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-1}$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

To add to above answers, using that $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $B$, one can show that:
\begin{align*} AB=A+B\Rightarrow A(B-I)=B\Rightarrow  A=\frac{B}{B-I}\Rightarrow (B-I)A=B\Rightarrow BA=A+B\end{align*}
This proves that the implication $\lambda\in\sigma(A)\Rightarrow\frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}\in\sigma(B)$ is actually an *equivalence*. Using the identity in N8tron's comment, the product formula is now very easy to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an even easier answer.

Let $x$ be the eigenvector associated with $\lambda$. Then $$
\lambda Ax = ABx = (A+B)x = Ax + Bx = Ax + \lambda x.
$$
This implies that $$
(\lambda - 1) Ax = \lambda x
$$
from which the results follows with $x$ being an eigenvector for $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda / (\lambda - 1)$.